# Can pull and clone but suddenly can't push

Tags: github

I suddenly wasn't able to push any of my repos, but I can still clone. This happened right after I connected to a new wifi at a cafe, and I suspect it had something to do with this? This is the error.

```
ERROR: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I use ssh (multiple accounts). Everything seems to check out when I run `git config --list`.

Running `git remote -v` gives the following (actual url taken out) which also seems fine?:

```
origin  git@github.com:[repo_url] (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:[repo_url] (push)
```

I also tried re-cloning the repo in a new folder which worked fine. But I still wasn't able to push any changes from the re-cloned repo.

BTW, I saw a similar question/solution where following [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain) to update credentials from the macOS Keychain worked. I tried, but I couldn't find any github.com entries.

Comment: Have you ever change user? Trying to check configuration for ssh key of your account.

Comment: hi @shanfeng ! What do you mean by change user? I also can't push from either github account I have on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you can try in this scenario:

**Solution 1:**

In case your ssh key is missing from ssh agent

```
// start the agent first by
eval `ssh-agent -s`

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
// id_rsa represents your ssh key associated with git repo
```

**Solution 2:**

Update your remote git-url

```
 // From SSH
 git@github.com:Gameonn/Sleepy-Quotes.git

 // To HTTPS
 https://github.com/Gameonn/Sleepy-Quotes.git
```

Comment: I think my ssh key is fine since I'm able to clone and pull (I tried solution 1 anyway, but no change). Same with the remote url. I'm just not able to push.

Comment: Have you tried changing your remote url to https because you were using ssh earlier? @xilinzhou